# Equality of trigonometric functions

Tags: trigonometry

I have

$\frac{\cos(a)}{\sin(a)}= \frac{\cos(b)}{\sin(b-c)}$

Does this imply something? I know that l.h.s. is

$\tan(a)$

And r.h.s. is

$\frac{\cos(b)}{[\sin(b)\cos(c)-\sin(c)\cos(b)]}$

But is there anything else?

$c>b>a$

Also b and a are $pc$ and $qc$ respectively

where $0<q,p<1$

Comment: @Dr. Sonnhard Graubner , thanks!!

Comment: It means that $\cot(a) = \cos(b) \csc(b - c)$. Although, I'm not sure if you want to find values where the identity is true.

Comment: The l.h.s. is $\cot(a)$, not $\tan(a)$. Another form of the equation is $$\tan a = \tan b \cos c - \sin c$$ But mostly it just tells you that if you know two of the three values, the third value can be determined, up to a point (if $a,b,c$ can vary over all real numbers, then there will always be an infinite number of solutions, but they will be discrete. If $a,b,c$ are restricted to $0$ to $2\pi$, then there will be exactly 2 solutions.)